# what happens when the command gcloud app deploy --version v1 is issued to deploy a nodejs application?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

Can any one help me understand `gcloud app deploy`? I tried deploying an application but it gave me the error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error
>   occurred while creating a Google Cloud Storage bucket.

Thanks,
-VR

Comment: Please show more info about the app, the exact code or command you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gcloud is google sdk command to interact with its cloud services, you can read more about it here https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/

you can run gcloud commands either by installing gcloud sdk or from a gcloud shell where sdk is pre-installed.
gcloud app deploy looks for app.yaml which can be configured based on this documentation https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml

To address the error try running this command gcloud config set app/use_deprecated_preparation True; and give a try.

once we run `gcloud app deploy --version v1` a version of the application is created and can be accessed by the corresponding url from version column.
one can even login to the running instance of VM by accessing respective instance ssh.

this command will tar ball the folder containing app.yaml and will be used to create the running nodejs instance; the entire deployment depends on PORT being used as part of NodeJS application for running production instance, and a proper package.json which will have all the dependencies listed and contains a start script to run the application.

￼[image: image showing a successful version]

Comment: gcloud config set app/use_deprecated_preparation -- helped; thanks for the time.